# How to inject data into my component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a component which outputs a sortable list, with some ajax crud built into it. This is just a simple component which I want to drop onto my page.

I am struggling to figure out how to get the existing list of items into the component.

My page is built using PHP and I already have an array of items for the list. So far the only way I've found to read the data is using `json_encode` to output the data to the dom in the page, and then read that using my component.

```
<script>
    window.faqs = <?= json_encode($provider->get('provider_faqs'));?>
</script>
```

I would much prefer to pass the json into the component as a prop, just as I do with the associated id field.

`<bbf-faqs v-bind:provider-id="<?= $provider->get('id')?>"></bbf-faqs>`

However when I try and pass json, my component cannot understand it, and just outputs the string. Nor does VueJS complain that I don't have the prop defined.

Is there a way to pass a object as a prop? Ideally I don't want the component to ajax away for data, but if it comes to that I suppose it'll have to do.

Comment: JSON encode the prop as you are with the faqs.

Comment: If I do that, and try to JSON.parse() it, I just get json in the dom

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, and it actually turned out to be rather a simple oversight.

When I was using my Vue tag I was assigning the HTML attribute using double quotes, which were not being escaped in my json string. As such my tag would break, due to the extra double quote.

So changing from this `<bbf-faqs data="<?= json_encode($stuff);?>">` to `<bbf-faqs data='<?= json_encode($stuff);?>'>` has solved it.

The other option, and probably more properly would be to escape the quotes in the json encode.

It's also worth noting that if you use `v-bind` on the json being passed it, it will be automatically evaluated to an array, with no need for JSON.parse

The other issue with this approach to injection is that a prop is not data, so does not have any data binding.

I don't think this is possible, so I'm going to use the dom variable approach

Answer (score -1):

Use JSON.parse() to convert your string into a JavaScript object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, nor give any direction as to how to use the method mentioned. It's also not necessary when using v-bind, so I have downvoted it. Feel free to improve your answer.